# Определить связь слов в словосочетании - управление, согласование

Tags: синтаксис

Верно ли я определил связь слов в словосочетании? **Множество вопросов** - управление, **части слова** - управление, **условные обозначения** - согласование. И подскажите, пожалуйста, почему слова **я ем** не являются словосочетанием?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1):

Связи определили верно. Сочетание **я ем** - не словосочетание, а предложение, грамматическая основа. Там связь особенная, предикативная. В грамматической основе не выделяется главное и зависимое слово.

Answer (score 1):

*Грамматическая основа* (предикативная) не является словосочетанием, это ядро простого предложения. А связи, как вам уже сказали, вы определили совершенно правильно, правда мне неясна ваша неуверенность: вопрос-то лёгкий!